# C++ Template Wildcard-like construct (or: How can I make Wildcards with a Template)

Tags: c++, templates, generics

So, as you might have already imagined, I'm trying to use wildcards in C++. But first, let me give you an example of what I mean:
Lets suppose we have a Human class and a Pocket class. The Pocket class has an arbitrary other class as an type argument. To visualize this better, let's write some code (in Java:)

Human.java:

```java
package de.budschie.human_pocket_example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Human 
{
    ArrayList<Pocket<?>> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Pocket.java:

```java
package de.budschie.human_pocket_example;

public class Pocket<E>
{
    E pocketElement;
    int amount;
    
    public Pocket(E pocketElement, int amount) 
    {
        this.pocketElement = pocketElement;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    
    public E getPocketElement() 
    {
        return pocketElement;
    }
    
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can store pockets, regardless of their type argument. I could create a pocket which contains a pocket which contains an Integer, and an other pocket, which contains a Float, and both would fit into the inventory. So, my question is:

#### How would I do that in C++?

I already tried to use the question mark, but that doesn't seem to have worked. I can't just say, that I want an std::vector<Pocket<?>>.

I hope that this is not off-topic for StackOverflow, and if it is, please tell me in the comments and I'll delete this question as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Can you show your c++ code and what is not working for you? How are you trying to use it? `template <typename T> void foo(std::vector<Pocket<T>> vec) {}` can support any `Pocket<T>`.

Comment: I would suggest picking up [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). What you want to do will be explained there as "templates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three key differences between Java and C++ to cope with here: the type system is different, templates are not generics, and vectors are not arraylists.

1. The type system:

   In Java, every instantiation of `Pocket<E>` still derives from `Object`, so there's some common base type to store a reference to.

   In C++, every instantiation of `Pocket<E>` is a distinct type, and there is no implicit inheritance of a root type. If you want every `Pocket<E>` to derive from something, you have to do that manually.
2. The type system again:

   Say you add a root for your hierarchy, `PocketBase`, from which every `Pocket<E>` derives.
   Since there is no root type, there's also no common base class for the different `E` types, and hence no common return type for the different `Pocket<E>::getPocketElement()`.

   You can just have it return [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), I guess, if that makes sense. But then you could just use `std::any` in `PocketBase` directly, because `Pocket<T>` isn't doing any more than that.
3. `std::vector` stores objects. If you want polymorphism, you need to store pointers instead. Again, you need to do this explicitly: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PocketBase>>` or whatever.

The basic hierarchy is something like this:

```
class PocketBase
{
protected:
  int amount_ = 0;

public:
  virtual ~PocketBase() = 0;

  int amount() const { return amount_; }
};

template <typename T>
class Pocket: public PocketBase
{
  T element_;
public:
  // etc. etc.
};
```

And now

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PocketBase>>
```

can store (pointers to) any mixture of `Pocket<T>` types.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making `Pocket` a non-template class and keep one [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) attribute inside to store any type of value.

```
    struct Human {
        struct Pocket {
            std::any thing; 
            std::size_t quantity;
        };
        std::vector<Pocket> pockets;
    };
```